# OnItemClickListener with SlidingNavigationDrawer

Tags: android

I have an android project and a sliding navigation drawer. I have built a management library that allows you add multiple different types of controls to the navigation menu.

I have a problem though that the OnItemClickListener isn't getting called. I've found "setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);" from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27 but this hasn't  helped.

Below is how my code is created:

```
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    public static Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment frag = new MainFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
        //t.commit();

        init(); 
        NavigationManager navManager = new NavigationManager(this, mDrawerLayout, 
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed); 

        navManager.prepareActionBar(); 

        NavigationManagerAdapter menuAdapter = new NavigationManagerAdapter(this);

        menuAdapter.add(new NavigationMenuItem("Products", "MENU_PRODUCTS",
                NavigationMenuItem.GuiType.TEXTVIEW, null));

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

}

```
private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

}
```

My FragmentActivity implements ListItem.OnItemClickListener.

Below is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#4e4e4e"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#111"
            android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

**UPDATE 1**

I've pinpointed where the issue is, and it is to do with my library.

If I add to the adapter in the following code it works:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
```

If I manually create my adapter with a custom adapter and set it the onitemclicklistener stops working.

Below is how I add to the adapter and set the adapter to the list view

```
NavigationManagerAdapter menuAdapter = new NavigationManagerAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        menuAdapter.add(new NavigationMenuItem("MenuItem", "MENU_PRODUCTS", GuiType.TEXTVIEW, null));

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
```

Below is the code for my `NavigationManagerAdapter`

```
public class NavigationManagerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavigationMenuItem>{

    public NavigationManagerAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        try
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_menu_item, null);

            if (getItem(position).iconRes != -1)
            {
                ImageView icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
                icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
                if (getItem(position).onClickListener != null)
                {
                    icon.setOnClickListener(getItem(position).onClickListener);
                }
            }

            switch (getItem(position).guiType)
            {
                case TEXTVIEW:
                    TextView standardTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_textview);
                    standardTextView.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                    standardTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (getItem(position).onClickListener != null)
                    {
                        standardTextView.setOnClickListener(getItem(position).onClickListener);
                    }
                    if (getItem(position).tag != null)
                    {
                        standardTextView.setTag(getItem(position).tag);
                    }
                    break;
                case HEADER:
                    TextView textViewHeader = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_header);
                    textViewHeader.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                    textViewHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case SUBHEADER:
                    TextView textViewSubHeader = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_subHeader);
                    textViewSubHeader.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                    textViewSubHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case SUB_TEXTVIEW:
                    TextView textViewSubItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_subTextView);
                    textViewSubItem.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                    textViewSubItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textViewSubItem.setOnClickListener(getItem(position).onClickListener);
                    textViewSubItem.setTag(getItem(position).tag);
                    break;
                case SWITCH:
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                    {
                        Switch switchButton = (Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_switch);
                        switchButton.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                        if (getItem(position).tag != null)
                        {
                            switchButton.setTag(getItem(position).tag);
                        }
                        switchButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(getItem(position).onCheckedChangeListener);
                        switchButton.setChecked(getItem(position).defaultValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ComponentNotSupportedOnApiException("Switches are not supported in API Version: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                    }
                    break;
                case TEXTVIEW_SUMMARY:
                    TextView spannedTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_textview);
                    String menuTitle = getItem(position).menuName;
                    String summary = getItem(position).summary;
                    spannedTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(menuTitle + "<br /><small><font color='#9f9f9f'>" + summary + "</font></small>"));
                    spannedTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (getItem(position).onClickListener != null)
                    {
                        spannedTextView.setOnClickListener(getItem(position).onClickListener);
                    }
                    if (getItem(position).tag != null)
                    {
                        spannedTextView.setTag(getItem(position).tag);
                    }
                    break;
                case HEADER_SUMMARY:
                    TextView spannedHeader = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_header);
                    String headerTitle = getItem(position).menuName;
                    String headerSummary= getItem(position).summary;
                    spannedHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(headerTitle + "<br /><small><font color='#000000'>" + headerSummary + "</font></small>"));
                    spannedHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case BUTTON:
                    Button button = null;
                    if (getItem(position).isBorderless)
                    {
                        button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_button_borderless);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_button);
                    }
                    button.setText(getItem(position).menuName);
                    button.setOnClickListener(getItem(position).onClickListener);
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (ComponentNotSupportedOnApiException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Adapter Error", ex.toString());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: I didn't set either android:clicakble="false" or the "blockDescendants" options on a similar layout, and it registers onItemClick events.  The "clickable=false" is suspicious to me, have you tried without?

Comment: Yea I've tried without both of them but still no working for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue.

I had to run the following so that the item click is passed to the list view.

```
standardTextView.setFocusable(false);
standardTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
standardTextView.setClickable(false);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The activity implementing the drawer should have a layout like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout> ...</RelativeLayout>

    // The Drawer list comes in the end
    <!-- Navigation List of the Drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width = "240dp"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
        android:divider = "#555"
        android:dividerHeight = "1dp"
        android:textColor = "#EEE"
        android:background = "#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in the activity

```
mDrawerList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_main_list);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerMainList));
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

This should be your DrawerItemClickListener

```
 // Drawer Item Click Listener
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(mMainContext, "Click on drawer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
}
```

Comment: No joy unfortunately, unfortunately changing the layout makes the menu always visible and you can't slide it out of the way. But either way unfortunetely doesn't fix the onitemclicklistener